# How to find a matrix to preserve one matrix and diagonize another matrix.

Tags: matrices

G is a positive-definite symmetric matrix, V is another symmetric matrix,ie $V\neq G$, All their elements are Real number. How to find a matrix O such that:

$$OGO^{T}=I$$
$$OVO^{T}=Diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2...\lambda_n)$$

Comment: Such a matrix may not exist.

Comment: In one paper, it says that such matrix always exist.

Comment: Are $\lambda_1,\dots$ eigenvalues of $V$?

Comment: I think so but not necessary. All I want is make V diagonal.

Comment: Since the case $V=G$ is allowed by the conditions specified in the question there is clearly a problem somwhere.

Comment: You **think** so? Sorry to say this but if you don't even put in the effort to post a question you understand, don't expect good answers to your question.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I not very sure, all I want to say is that there exist O to preserve G and diagonize V. By preserving G, we can get det(O)=1, so definitely  Product of all $\lambda$ s are the product of eigenvalues of V, but I can not prove that they are the same.

Comment: Just a remark: if you replace $OGO^T=G$ with $OGO^T=I$ you will get the [simultaneous diagonalization of two Hermitian matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization). I suspect your problem is somehow related, but you are missing an *extra relation* between $V$ and $G$.

Comment: xjtan, ***you need to learn to give the actual reference, title and authors, also typeset the actual equation as part of your original question,*** and explain why you think that equation becomes the simplified matrix question you are asking here.

Comment: Will, thanks for your advice on how to ask questions.

Comment: After I take Will Jagy's advice, I try to edit the question and go back to the original paper I was reading, and find that I misunderstood the paper and asked an wrong question. The author means simultaneous diagonalization of two Hermitian matrices just as A.G. mentioned. I am so terribly sorry to waste all you guys' time. I will be much more careful in the future. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of having an answer, this is called *simultaneous diagonalisation by congruence* and the method is well-known. Since $G$ is positive definite, it has a unique positive definite square root $G^{1/2}$. Now let $O=QG^{-1/2}$ for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$. Then the first equation is automatically satisfied, and the second one means that $QG^{-1/2}VG^{-1/2}Q^T$ is diagonal. Now the latter is solvable because $G^{-1/2}VG^{-1/2}$ is real symmetric and hence real orthogonally diagonalisable.